# how can I update ng-model dynamically from inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I'm new to Angular and can't figure out what I am doing wrong while trying to get ng-model to display an object value.

**The goal:**

I want to create a directive that reads an Object and generates radio buttons based on Object data. Inside of this Object I have {logAs: 'radioGroupName'}. This should get stored into another object called formData.

**Example:**

```
{logAs: 'dog', options: [{option: 'poodle'}, {option: 'pitbull'}]}
```

This should create two radio buttons, one for pittbull and another for poodle. Both should have ng-model set to dog. If user selects Poodle then final output in the formData Object should be:

```
{dog: 'poodle'}
```

**The Issue:**

I believe I am close, everything works fine except for ng-model. Inside of ng-model the actual Object value (dog) wont show up as I'd like, instead I get the Object path that I typed in.

**This is my html:**

```
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p>formData: {{formData}}</p>
    <h3>Static (updates formData)</h3>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.dog" value="pitbull"> Pitbull<br/>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.dog" value="Bull Dog"> Bull Dog<br/>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.dog" value="Poodle"> Poodle

    <h3>Dynamic (wont update formData)</h3>
    <directive form="formInfo"></directive>
  </div>
```

**This is the Javascript:**

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.formInfo = {
    title: 'What type of dog do you have?',
    logAs: 'dog',
    options: [{option:'Pitbull'}, {option: 'Bull Dog'}, {option:'Poodle'}]
  }
})

.directive('directive', function(){
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '{{form.title}}<div ng-repeat="option in form.options"> <input type="radio" ng-model="form.logAs" value="jack" > {{option.option}}</div>',
    scope: {
        form: '='
    }

  }
});
```

**How can I get ng-model to show the output of the object ('dog') instead of the object path?**
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juanarcin/ttjmdxeo/10/)

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, it's because on line 3 of your html, you have `{{formData}}` when it should be `{{formData.dog}}`

Comment: Still wrong. How `formData` is displayed has nothing to do with the directive not working as intended.

Comment: @ChrisG What does the second to last line of his question ask? It's in bold. In the section with the heading "The issue" -- also in bold -- what does that say?

Comment: It says implicitly, just like it is spelled out in the fiddle, that clicking the radio buttons doesn't update `formData`. OP has already identified the issue: generated HTML based on the template doesn't look like he expects. You should only use condescension when you actually know what you're talking about.

Comment: My answer addressed the explicit question and explicit issue as noted in the original post from OP.  If you believe additional implicit questions are being asked, you should note that to OP so he has an opportunity to edit his post for clarity -- especially before downvotting an answer that directly addresses his foremost question.

Comment: To clarify, when I ask how "How can I get ng-model to show the output of the object ('dog') instead of the object path?" I am talking about the attribute ng-model in the input tag.